# how to limit data entry in the list in python

Tags: python

These 4 lists should only receive 3 data from each one (name, number, age).

How to make it look like Example 2?

For example:

```
import random

A, B, C, D = [], [], [], []

for k in range(12):

name= input('Whats your name: ')
number = int(input('one number: '))
age = int(input('Other number: '))

x = random.choice([A, B, C, D])
x.append(name + " " + str(number) +" " + str(age))
```

Example 2:

```
List A :
Name : jean
number: 30
age: 15

Name : Jhon
number: 15
age: 25

Name: pedro
number: 19
age: 19
```

And  other lists keeping that same style (the lists are random).

Comment: See this link on how to ask a question on this site: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Good information man!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an implementation. You can use a nestled list, and then shuffle it once you're done to preserve randomness.

```
data_lists = [[], [], [], []]

for k in data_lists:
    name = input('Whats your name: ')
    number = int(input('one number: '))
    age = int(input('Other number: '))

    k.append(name + " " + str(number) + " " + str(age))

random.shuffle(data_lists)

print(data_lists[0])
print(data_lists[1])
print(data_lists[2])
print(data_lists[3])
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: when can I use choice instead of shuffle?

Comment: @abdelhamedabdin `choice` picks any random element from the list. `shuffle` swaps the items randomly within the list. So if you wanted to _display_ a random item you'd use `choice`. If you wanted to randomise the order of the list you'd use `shuffle`